# dropdown selection issue in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, templates

Hi i am working in one mvc project where i am stuck on very small issue of dropdown selection.

There are 2 dropdown.1st used for country name and 2nd one is used for tourism type.

And one button used for search according to dropdown selection.

Here is the link of the website:

www.ourplanettravel.com.au/

If we select "Tasmania" from 1st dropdown  and "Tours & Cruises"  from 2nd dropdown and click search button then,2nd dropdown looses its value(it shows  --Choose Tourism Type-- ) only in this case, while in other options it works perfectly.

Here is the code that i am using:

```
     <select id='TourismType' name="TourismType"> 
       <option value=''>--Choose Tourism Type--</option>   
       {{if $item.data.oTourismType}} 
         {{each  $item.data.oTourismType}}

    <option value='${Text}'>${Text}</option>
     {{/each}} 

   </select> 
     {{/if}}
```

Please suggest me where i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the dropdown retains its value in the current instance of the view (hence "Tours & Cruises" is part of the query string after you search and is included in your search results), but doesn't retain its value in the dropdown itself. Basically the model that gets passed to the view that will be displayed when you go to the next page does not have the selected tourism type bound. You can rebind the property in the controller.

However, in general, I would recommend using Razor helpers to do your model binding rather than an explicit  tag, which may avoid this issue in the first place.

Generic example with a single dropdown...

Model

```
public class YourModel {
    public int SelectedTourismType { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TourismType> TourismTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Tourism type class:

```
public class TourismType {
    public int TourismTypeID { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    // other properties if applicable
}
```

View:

```
@model YourModel

// Your form or whatever here...

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedTourismType,
    new SelectList(Model.TourismTypes, "TourismTypeID", "DisplayNameName"),
    "Select an option") // Default text before the user has selected an option
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult YourAction()
{
    YourModel model = new YourModel();
    model.TourismTypes= new List<TourismType> {
        new TourismType { TourismTypeID = 1, Value = "Tours & Cruises" },
        new TourismType { TourismTypeID = 2, Value = "Some other type name" }
    }

    return View("YourViewName", model);
}
```

This should work as long as you are passing through the same model when you refresh the view on the following page. Of course you would need to modify it to include both dropdowns, one dependent on the other.

Comment: you are right,but why its working for all other options of same dropdown.can you please check this link..  http://www.ourplanettravel.com.au/